# TextAreaSample JTextArea JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, text-files, jtextfield, jtextarea

I'm gonna show the deneme2.txt and deneme1.txt in the same area. But only I have a result for deneme1.txt.  I wanna show the deneme2.txt on the left side. but I can't do it.

can you help me please?

I have a problem when i was sharing, sorry for the code  sharing.

```
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextAreaSample
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String title = (args.length == 0 ? "TextArea Example" : args[0]);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JTextArea leftTextArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane rightPane = new JScrollPane(leftTextArea);

    try
    {
        leftTextArea.read(new FileReader("C:\\Denemeler\\deneme2.txt"), null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    content.add(leftTextArea);

    JTextArea rightTextArea = new JTextArea()
        {
            public boolean isManagingFocus()
            {
                return false;
            }
        };

    JScrollPane leftPane1 = new JScrollPane(rightTextArea);
    JScrollPane rightPane1 = new JScrollPane(leftTextArea);
    try
    {
        leftTextArea.read(new FileReader("C:\\Denemeler\\deneme1.txt"), null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    content.add(leftPane1);
    content.add(rightPane1);
    frame.setSize(250, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: manage and refactor your code. if in eclipse, use ctrl+a to select all and ctrl+shift+f to format it to this in seconds. then highlight members and press ctrl+shift+r on them to rename them across the project. after you've cleaned up your leftPanes going right into rightPane1.add(leftTextPane) discrepancies, it should be easier to continue working on this code later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the problem :

this
`leftTextArea.read(new FileReader("C:\\Denemeler\\deneme2.txt"),null);` should be `rightTextArea.read(new FileReader("C:\\Denemeler\\deneme2.txt"),null);`

so the over all program is :

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class QueueTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String title = (args.length == 0 ? "TextArea Example" : args[0]);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        JTextArea leftTextArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane rightPane = new JScrollPane(leftTextArea);
// JScrollPane leftPane = new JScrollPane(rightTextArea);
        JTextArea rightTextArea = new JTextArea();/* {
            public boolean isManagingFocus() { // i don't know why you have done this
                return false;
            }
        };*/
        try {
            rightTextArea.read(new FileReader("C:\\Denemeler\\deneme2.txt"), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        content.add(leftTextArea);
        leftTextArea.paste();
        rightTextArea.paste();
        JScrollPane leftPane1 = new JScrollPane(rightTextArea);
        JScrollPane rightPane1 = new JScrollPane(leftTextArea);
        try {
            leftTextArea.read(new FileReader("C:\\Denemeler\\deneme1.txt"), null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        content.add(leftPane1);
        content.add(rightPane1);
        frame.setSize(250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

there are lots of mistakes but this will give output.

Comment: mm, not really. first off, the rightTextArea is commented out, secondly, leftTextArea is used twice... read the code now... it's a mess.

Comment: also, please explain this... left panel adding right text area, and right pane adding left text area...
    JScrollPane leftPane1 = new JScrollPane(rightTextArea);
    JScrollPane rightPane1 = new JScrollPane(leftTextArea);

Comment: nope, i just formatted his code. selected his code, dropped it into my eclipse, formatted and submitted an editorial to his post. i skimmed thru it because it had compilation errors and saw too many misleads and unused members to bother getting up to get my glasses...

but i think at some point the leftPane gets reused (on accident?) which is why i suspect he sees only one. and having mixed up left vs right logic, he thinks he sees the wrong one.

Comment: @vstl completed own your own or what ??

Comment: unless this is the actual answer, it might be better if he made a new answer explaining what he did to accomplish the question and accept his own answer. (according to the faq)

Comment: your code is still same with me. but i have completed. also thank you for your help

Comment: I have one question for you. if I compare these text files and I want the the differences should seem to be bold, how can i do that?